# Error while executing pipeline with parameters

Tags: batch-file, jenkins

**Update:**

When I use `set` **before** `"` double quotes `set "JAVA_OPTS=..."` it throws

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
```

**Jenkins code**

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Denvironment=%environment% -DloginUrl=%loginUrl% -Dusername=%username% -Dpassword=%password% -DuserCount=%userCount% -DprojectName=%projectName%"
"D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\bin\gatling.bat" -s testFile
```

**Console Output**

```
D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\workspace>set "JAVA_OPTS=-Denvironment=https://test.com -DloginUrl=https://test1.com -Dusername=qauser -Dpassword=qauser -DuserCount=1 -DprojectName=Test" 
D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\workspace>"D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\bin\gatling.bat" -s testFile 
GATLING_HOME is set to "D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5"
JAVA = ""D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe""
Error: Could not find or load main class Test
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

**=====AND=====**

When I use `set` **after** `"` double quotes `"set JAVA_OPTS=..."` **it executes with default parameters which are passed in script NOT taking/Overwriting with Choice parameters**

**Jenkins code**

```
"set JAVA_OPTS=-Denvironment=%environment% -DloginUrl=%loginUrl% -Dusername=%username% -Dpassword=%password% -DuserCount=%userCount% -DprojectName=%projectName%"
"D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\bin\gatling.bat" -s testFile
```

**Console Output**

```
D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\workspace>"set JAVA_OPTS=-Denvironment=https://test.com -DloginUrl=https://test1.com -Dusername=qauser -Dpassword=qauser -DuserCount=1 -DprojectName=Test"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\workspace>"D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\bin\gatling.bat" -s testFile 
GATLING_HOME is set to "D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5"
JAVA = ""D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe""
12:00:22.246 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - Inputs = {
12:00:22.249 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - classpath = {
12:00:22.249 [DEBUG] i.g.c.ZincCompiler$ - D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\lib\t-digest-3.1.jar
....
....
Finished: SUCCESS
```

[image]

Comment: Please post your pipeline code. I believe a bit that you're not using [tag:jenkins-pipeline]. I've lost all my Windows batch knowledge, but I would expect that you would have to quote the variable contents, i.e., `JAVA_OPTS="..."` also on Windows.

Comment: In general, if you really use jenkins pipelines, then it's Groovy and it applies string interpolation only for double-quoted strings (`"${environment}"`), but _not_ for single-quoted ones (`'${environment}'`).

Comment: @StephenKing I have updated the question. Please check.

Comment: As expected, this is not using [Jenkins Pipelines](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/).

Comment: @StephenKing This is Freestyle project in jenkins

Comment: @StephenKing please check latest update of this question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about freestyle jobs.

Comment: @Mofi Thanks for the reply. 
I have tried with below code. It executes but not with Given parameters. it executes with default parameters.
`SET "JAVA_OPTS = -Denvironment=%environment% -DloginUrl=%loginUrl% -Dusername=%username% -Dpassword=%password% -DuserCount=%userCount% -DprojectName=%projectName%"
CALL D:\Progra~1\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\bin\gatling.bat -s abcFile`

Could you please help me why it is not passing given parameters?

Comment: @Mofi **I've tried with below calls but it says Unknown argument 'myFile'**
`D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\workspace>SET "JAVA_OPTS = -Denvironment=a -DloginUrl=a ... -DuserCount=1 -DprojectName=Abcde"`


`D:\Program Files\Jenkins\jobs\workspace>CALL "D:\Progra~1\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\bin\gatling.bat" -s myFile 


GATLING_HOME is set to "D:\Program Files\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5"`
`JAVA = "D:\Java\jdk1.8.0_25\bin\java.exe"`
`Warning: Unknown option -s`
`Warning: Unknown argument 'myFile'`

Comment: @Mofi When I execute gatling.bat it list downs so many files. I want to select `myFile` only and execute it How can I do it?
This fails
`CALL "D:\Progra~1\Jenkins\GATLING2.2.5\gatling-charts-highcharts-bundle-2.2.5\bin\gatling.bat" -s myFile`
What is the right syntax to call `myFile`?